# Why const pointer difference cannot be used as initializer for a static variable?

Tags: c

Compiling following piece of C code (using MSVC):

```
char * const p1;
char * const p2;
static size_t sz = p2 - p1;
```

results in "initializer is not a constant" error for definition of sz.

As pointers are const (tried also with arrays, same error), why is pointer diff not constant?

Comment: `constant` in this case means known at compile time.

Comment: This would work fine if `p1` and `p2` were initialized.

Comment: Peter, following code fails only for s:
    char a[2];
    static size_t s = &a[1]-&a[0];
    static char *p = a;

Comment: 0x5453, I have just tried to initialize p1 and p2, still getting the same error

Comment: @Peter: No, it does not. Constant expressions in initializers may be address constants, which are resolved by the linker or program loader, after compile time (possibly when the program is actually executing, for dynamically loaded libraries). They may also be address constants plus or minus integer constant expressions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil But not the difference of two address constants, no? (unless the implementation accepts other forms).

Comment: Const doesn't mean what you think it does; for example `const int a=2, b=3, c=b-a;` won't compiler either.

Comment: @mevets, I believe const is not really paramount to the error, but to the point raised by Eric Postpischil in the answer below: 'for constants used in initializers, C standard only requires implementations to support an arithmetic constant expression', and the value  of a variable (even const) is not written in the definition of a 'arith const expression'. 
PS: even const int a = 1, b = a; does not work

Comment: @CristianAlexandruMacarascu To anybody familiar with any language where const means something (other that pointless irritation) it is the source of surprise.  It is normally the definition of a constant.  *Standard* C added it to remind us of committee incompetence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per C 2018 6.6 7, for constants used in initializers, the C standard only requires implementations to support an *arithmetic constant expression*, a *null pointer constant*, an *address constant*, or an *address constant* for a complete object type plus or minus an *integer constant expression*. None of these include the subtraction of two addresses, as shown by their definitions below.

A C implementation might be able to resolve the subtraction of two addresses of symbols of the same kind, especially if the compiler can see they will be placed in the same program segment, and the C standard permits an implementation to do this. However, the standard does not require a C implementation to support this, and that is at least in part because the subtraction of two symbols may involve various difficulties. One is that two symbols might refer to objects in different program segments, such as one in a constant read-only section and another in an uninitialized data section. The compiler could not know the relative difference between these sections because it depends on contributions from other object modules linked into the program, and the object module format might not support any way of expressing this difference as something to be resolved by the linker. Even within one section, some object module and symbol schemes may allow the linker to rearrange things, to optimize for alignment issues.

Per 6.6 8:

> An *arithmetic constant expression* shall have arithmetic type and shall only have operands that are integer constants, floating constants, enumeration constants, character constants, `sizeof` expressions whose results are integer constants, and `_Alignof` expressions. Cast operators in an arithmetic constant expression shall only convert arithmetic types to arithmetic types, except as part of an operand to a `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operator.

Per 6.6 9:

> An *address constant* is a null pointer, a pointer to an lvalue designating an object of static storage duration, or a pointer to a function designator; it shall be created explicitly using the unary `&` operator or an integer constant cast to pointer type, or implicitly by the use of an expression of array or function type. The array-subscript `[]` and member-access `.` and `->` operators, the address `&` and indirection `*` unary operators, and pointer casts may be used in the creation of an address constant, but the value of an object shall not be accessed by use of these operators.

Per 6.3.2.3 3:

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, is called a *null pointer constant*.…

Per 6.6 6:

> An *integer constant expression* shall have integer type and shall only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, sizeof expressions whose results are integer constants, `_Alignof` expressions, and floating constants that are the immediate operands of casts. Cast operators in an integer constant expression shall only convert arithmetic types to integer types, except as part of an operand to the `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operator.

Comment: The key seems to me to be "the object module format might not support any way of expressing this difference as something to be resolved by the linker", and I was not aware there exists formats in which linker cannot resolve 'my' arith expression. In this case (linker cannot), compiler is forced to generate runtime code for initialization, thus it is not constant. Thank you!